# How to delete an array of array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have an array like this :

```
[[a,b],[c,d]]
```

How can I delete the outer array so it becomes:

```
[a,b],[c,d]
```

I tried using unset but cannot find a solution.

i got this answer by asign arrays in loops to another variable.. so how can i access the loops outside the loop it self?

```
    foreach($arr3 as $key => $value)
{
    $newArr[$key] = $value;

    echo json_encode($value); // this will answer my question
}
      echo json_encode($value); // when i echo outside loop it will not display as inside loop
```

Comment: If you do that, you'd need separate variables to store them

Comment: inner array?.. how to do that?

Comment: forgot to mention that my array is looping with database

Comment: why people said it off topic when there are answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to do this is as below.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $newArr[$key] = $value;
}
```

`$newArr` contains new array which you are asking.

**Comment Response**

You can also con cat it.

```
$concat = "";
foreach($arr3 as $key => $value)
{
    $newArr[$key] = $value;
    $concat .= json_encode($value).',';
}
echo rtrim($concat,',');
```

Comment: Its not `$k`, its `$key`. I was going to edit it but then thought better bring it to your notice. On another note, this simply does what `$newArray=$array;` can do. Why use a loop then.

Comment: Still that's not needed. This loop is only assigning the whole array to another variable that's it. It can simply be done by an `=` operator if that was desired

Comment: how to acces $value outside the foreach?

Comment: if i used echo json_encode($value); inside the loop .. it just work fine.. how to get the data outside loop?

Comment: sorry.. got an error.. missing , comma .. i got [a,b][c,d] without comma

Comment: @airi then edit this line `$concat .= json_encode($value);` and change that to `$concat .= json_encode($value).',';`

Comment: it works but at the end it got additonal comma.. [],[], how to remove the comma [a,b],[c,d], <--- addtional comma

Comment: @airi see my edited answer use `rtrim`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not delete the outer array. You can simply access the index of the array and cast it to another array.

As an example;

```
$arr = array(array('x','y'),array('z'));
```

You can access this with;

```
$arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array2=$array[0];
$array3=$array[1];
unset($array);
```